# Selecting DateTime Values with intervals greater than 45 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of ID's and Dates ordered from oldest to newest.  I'd like to select all ID's and Dates where the difference to the next previous date (with matching ID) is 45 days or greater.

```
202185, 2021-10-01 09:35:000
202185, 2021-10-02 09:36:000
202185, 2021-10-03 09:14:000
202185, 2022-02-01 09:22:000
202185, 2022-02-02 09:23:000
301133, 2021-11-01 09:35:000
301133, 2021-11-02 09:36:000
301133, 2021-11-03 09:14:000
301133, 2021-12-06 09:22:000
301133, 2022-01-25 09:23:000
```

SELECTION RETURNS:

```
202185, 2022-02-01 09:22:000
301133, 2022-01-25 09:23:000
```

Is there an efficient way to handle this using SQL Server?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into `lag(dt) over (partition by id)` and `datediff(day, <start>, <end>)`

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, date 
from (
    select id, [date], 
        datediff(day, lag([date]) over (partition by id order by [date]), [date]) as daydiff
    from [MyTable]
) t
where t.dayDiff >= 45
order by id, [date];
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69b5b976154d52a04333fbb1b771b3e1

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT A.* FROM MyTable A 
WHERE A.date >  
( SELECT DATEADD(day, 45, MAX(b.date))
  FROM MyTable B
  WHERE B.ID = A.ID 
  AND   B.date < A.date
)
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=038a3d02461f0ea54a14140e6be22370

Answer (score 0):

RHere is a solution using `LAG()` in a CTE.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE idz(
>         ID INT,
>         DAT DATETIME);
> INSERT INTO idz VALUES
> (202185, '2021-10-01 09:35:000'),
> (202185, '2021-10-02 09:36:000'),
> (202185, '2021-10-03 09:14:000'),
> (202185, '2022-02-01 09:22:000'),
> (202185, '2022-02-02 09:23:000'),
> (301133, '2021-11-01 09:35:000'),
> (301133, '2021-11-02 09:36:000'),
> (301133, '2021-11-03 09:14:000'),
> (301133, '2021-12-06 09:22:000'),
> (301133, '2022-01-25 09:23:000');
> ```

> ```
> WITH i AS
> ( SELECT
>   ID,
>   DAT,
>   LAG(DAT) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID
>           ORDER BY DAT) DAT_1
> FROM idz)
> SELECT
>   ID,
>   DAT,
>   DAT_1,
>   DATEDIFF(DAY,DAT_1,DAT) DD
> FROM i
> WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,DAT_1,DAT)>= 45
> ```

> ```
>     ID | DAT                     | DAT_1                   |  DD
> -----: | :---------------------- | :---------------------- | --:
> 202185 | 2022-02-01 09:22:00.000 | 2021-10-03 09:14:00.000 | 121
> 301133 | 2022-01-25 09:23:00.000 | 2021-12-06 09:22:00.000 |  50
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d3be0e4d3d752be217ea3a7e871b1c7)*

Credit due to shawnt00